# Plone 4.1 - Running bin/buildout crashes while setting up a fresh installation - zope.configuration 3.7.4. not recognized

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

I'm using Plone 4.1 and trying to run `bin/buildout` in a fresh directory, having just managed to get `python bootstrap.py --distribute` to work.  `bin/buildout` runs along fine for a couple of minutes, downloading various distributions, then crashes with the following report:

```
Getting distribution for 'plone.recipe.zope2instance==4.1.7'.
Got plone.recipe.zope2instance 4.1.7.
... (many distributions omitted for brevity) ...
Getting distribution for 'zope.container==3.11.2'.
Got zope.container 3.11.2.
Getting distribution for 'zope.configuration==3.7.4'.
error: Not a recognized archive type: /Users/Jon/.buildout/downloads/dist/zope.configuration-3.7.4.zip
An error occured when trying to install zope.configuration 3.7.4. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section instance.
  Initializing section instance.
  Installing recipe plone.recipe.zope2instance.
  Getting distribution for 'zope.configuration==3.7.4'.
Error: Couldn't install: zope.configuration 3.7.4
```

It looks like the important error message is: **Not a recognized archive type: /Users/Jon/.buildout/downloads/dist/zope.configuration-3.7.4.zip**

Incidentally, I tried simply re-running `bin/buildout` and it picked up in a new place, starting with:

```
Getting distribution for 'zdaemon==2.0.4'.
Got zdaemon 2.0.4.
Getting distribution for 'pytz==2011g'.
Got pytz 2011g.
```

...and so on.  Can I just keep retrying the script until it successfully get all the stuff that it needs?

Also, I tried running `bin/buildout` for version 4.2 in another directory, and that seemed to work okay.

**EDIT** The second time I ran `bin/buildout` it completed without crashing.  However, I did a search of the output and it never once downloaded anything with "configuration" in it's name.  So what is going on???

**EDIT** Just for good measure I tried running `bin/buildout` a third time and it exited quickly after printing the single line "Updating instance."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're fine. I suspect you have a less than ideal network connection and/or that PyPI is having problems (one of your other posts was about network related issues as well, I think).

The error you saw is that it's tried to download a zip file that's been corrupted, and so it fails to extract the zip file. On your second attempt, it downloaded it successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance.  I guess I don't understand why `zope.configuration==3.7.4` never appeared again in the output when I re-ran buildout, but if I'm good to go then that's all I need for now.

Comment: Check your eggs dir for zope.configuration, if it's there already then the dep is satisfied and it won't be downloaded again. Also check your downloads/dist dir, if the distribution is there buildout will use it instead of checking pypi (by default at least IIRC)